# Geometric Interpretation of QFT Scattering Integrals

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^k)$, and $g\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$, where $k<n$. How do I compute
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\delta^k(f(\mathbf{x}))\cdot g(\mathbf{x})\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}$$
where $\delta$ is the dirac-delta function? I have a hypothesis:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\delta^k(f(\mathbf{x}))\cdot g(\mathbf{x})\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}=\int_{f^{-1}(\mathbf{0})}g(\mathbf{y})\mathrm{d}\mathbf{y}$$
Where $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{y}$ is the euclidean volume form on the manifold $~f^{-1}(\mathbf{0})\subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Is this correct?

Comment: The first option doesn't make sense ($f$ can only pull back a $1$-form on $\Bbb R$), and nor does the second, in general, as you can't integrate an $n$-form over a hypersurface. Are you sure you mean $\delta\circ f$? Actuallly, this is a very subtle question: Currents on a manifold generalize distributions on Euclidean space.

Comment: I'm sure that's what I mean - Thanks for the reply - now I know that my guesses don't make sense. But it looks like a solution could be incredibly deep and revealing.

Comment: I changed the question to pertain to euclidean space - from there the generalization to manifolds shouldn't be too hard, I suppose

Comment: This is of interest: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function

Comment: Interesting. In the wiki page they only present $f$ as a real-valued function - I wonder how it generalizes to $f$ as a vector-valued function

Comment: @Dave, the "generalization to $n$ dimensions" section discusses $\int_{\mathbf{R}^n} \delta(g(\mathbf{x}))\, f(g(\mathbf{x}))\, |\det g'(\mathbf{x})|\, d\mathbf{x} = \int_{g(\mathbf{R}^n)} \delta(\mathbf{u}) f(\mathbf{u})\,d\mathbf{u}$ and $\int_{\mathbf{R}^n} f(\mathbf{x}) \, \delta(g(\mathbf{x})) \, d\mathbf{x} = \int_{g^{-1}(0)}\frac{f(\mathbf{x})}{|\mathbf{\nabla}g|}\,d\sigma(\mathbf{x}) $

Comment: Another topic in physics where these integrals show up are in density of states calculations in condensed matter theory. A particular example of that: If we identify $g$ with the energy and $\mathbf{k}$ with the momentum, then the fact that @AlexNelson's expression diverges when $\Delta g=0$ is known in solid state physics as a [Van Hove singularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Hove_singularity). This Physics SE question may be of interest as well: [The definition of Density of states](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55243/55641).